# Changing from list item to list detail component using React-Router on SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a single page app where I have list items rendered on the right side of the page after an ajax call.

I want to be able to click on the individual list items and get a list detail page (AlbumList) that takes the place of the list component (TrackList). However, when I click on the list items, it shows the correct path and track Id but nothing happens.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = store.getState();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    store.subscribe(() => this.setState(store.getState()))
  }

  ajaxCall(cityname, pagenumber) {
    $.ajax({
      url: `#`,
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    })
    .done((data) => {    
      let mappedArray = data.message.body.track_list.map((x) =>{
        return {
          trackId: x.track.track_id,
          trackName: x.track.track_name,
          artistName: x.track.artist_name
        }
      })

      const action = {type: 'CHANGE_TRACK_LIST', list: mappedArray}
      store.dispatch(action);

    });
  }

    render(){
      return(
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Maps changeList={this.ajaxCall} pageNumber={this.state.pageNumber}/>
            <div className="list-result-container">
            <TrackList list={this.state.artists} changePage={this.ajaxCall}/>
            </div>
            <Route path='/track' component={TrackList}/>
            <Route path='/track/:id' component={AlbumList}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }


ReactDOM.render((
  <App />
), document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In TrackList Component -

```
let items = this.props.list.map(x => {
  return(
      <Link to={`/track/${x.trackId}`}>
      <li key={x.trackId} className="artist-items">
      "{x.trackName}"<br />
      <span className="artist-name">by {x.artistName}</span>
      </li>
      </Link>

    );
```

Comment: Looks like it's because you are not routing to the `TrackList` component, so it will always be there. You need to turn that component into a unique route so when you change urls, the component that gets rendered will change. Looks like you are halfway there with the `AlbumList` component. Do the same thing to `TrackList`.

Comment: I added another Route for the Tracklist component, it's still doing the same thing. `<Route path='/tracks' component={TrackList}/>`

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code?

Comment: Okay I edited it

Comment: You need to remove the component and replace it with the route. Remove this code:

`<div className="list-result-container">
            <TrackList list={this.state.artists} changePage={this.ajaxCall}/>
            </div>
`